# Track errors in snowflake - Error during validate function in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Executed a copy command using stage and also direct S3 location in snowflake with ON_ERROR = CONTINUE;
and then used select * from table(validate(test, job_id=>'_last')); to track the error records however i received the following error after execution the validate command "Failure using stage area. Cause: [The AWS Access Key Id you provided is not valid.]"
Could someone please help with error.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to list the file from S3 using snowflake list command?

Comment: Yes, working fine now. Initially i was trying with S3 URL directly and not stage but then tried stage approach and it worked fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Retried the same with new setup and its working fine.